# Syntax for dividing two complex numbers in wolframalpha

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, complex-numbers

I would like to dive two complex number:

a = 440 angle (10 degrees)
b = 39 - 18i

I would like to know the syntax for calculating a/b

Comment: Assuming this is homework, I'll give hints. Do you know how to use sine and cosine to get the real and imaginary parts of a complex vector? That is the first step. Do you know that Mathematica is case sensitive and if you don't capitalize correctly it will fail. That is the second step. Look up Sin, Cos and I in the help system. That should give you enough hints so you can learn how to use this rather than learn how to type in the answer someone gave you.

Comment: Dividing two complex numbers in mathematica is done using the "/" operator, the same as for real numbers or integers. Don't forget to use parenthesis and I (capital) for the square root of -1, as in  (1+3 I)/(7-11 I). As Bill said, you will have first to convert the data about a into a complex number with real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to convert the polar form of `a` to real and imaginary parts:

(r, θ) = r*(cos(θ) + i*sin(θ))

Head over to Wikipedia if you need a quick refresher. As for the Wolfram Alpha input, you can just write it verbatim:

```
440*(cos(10) + i*sin(10)) / (39 - 18i)
```

Note that in the first formula, θ is measure in radians, but Wolfram Alpha automatically convert it to degrees for you.